# A function to generate up to N virtual unique records

Tags: postgresql

In my database app stress-testing, I need to be able to execute a function that produces a huge number of unique records.

Is it possible to implement a function in PostgreSql that would take a parameter - number of records to be generated, and then produce that many records of some virtual structure that I could later tweak?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION generate_records(N)

/*
    generate N unique records of some random structure;
*/
```

I want to avoid creating actual tables with many millions of records for automated stress-testing, because I am not testing performance of the database, I am testing data-processing performance of a client that consumes a lot of data.

Comment: generate_series()?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to be able to tweak the returned structure, as stated. I do not want it fixed to a single-column numbers generation, it would make a poor test. Also, I need to tweak it so it would match a specific structure used by the app.

Comment: `select g.id, 'foo' as name, 'bar' as code, current_date as due_date from generate_series(1,1e6) as g(id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's perfect! Do you want t make this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for this.

To create a specific structure, just select the columns you want:

```
select g.id, 
       (random() * 99) + 1)::int as status_code
       gen_random_uuid() as some_uid,
       date '2000-01-01' + (random() * 8000):int as due_date 
from generate_series(1,1e6) as g(id);
```